# Is there a way to have javascript draw the latitude and longitude lines on a svg world map?

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a Javascript function that can help me draw the latitude and longitude lines on a world map, and have them scaled to the size of the map? I thought I saw something like that many years ago, but unable to find any reference to it now.

Comment: Its possible to draw lines, you would have to determine where you want them though.

Comment: `a Javascript function` - not built in, if that's what you mean. You have to write the code yourself such that it relates to whatever "svg world map" you happen to be using